# Ionic 3 Input Percentage Mask

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, ionic3

I'd like to hear any advice or recommendation on how to accomplish this. The requirement is to create an input mask directive that only allows the user to enter numbers, optionally 2 decimals, and it also has the % symbol inside the input field. Any idea, or if there is anything already built for this would be very appreciated,
thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the directive you used? url?

Comment: Hi @Sampath, I didnt, I coulndt find any good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following Sam advice, solved with text-mask:

```
<input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="percent"
[textMask]="{mask: mask, pipe: percentage, guide:false}" />
```

and..

```
mask(obj) {
    return [ /\d/, /\d|./, /\d|./, /\d/, /\d/ ];
};

percentage(value) {
    var num = value.replace('%', '');
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        if (num % 1 != 0) {
            num = parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
        }
        return num + '%';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope you can use [**text-mask**](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme) module.

But you need to install `Ionic 3` compatible version as shown below.

```
npm install angular2-text-mask@8.0.2 --save
```

*Change `package.json` as below (i.e. remove `^`)*

```
  "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.2",
```

This `module` has a lot of features. See the above link.

**Update:** If you're using `Lazy loading` then you must import `TextMaskModule` inside either `page's module` or `shared.module.ts` and also you need to set the `maxlength` on the `ion-input` to avoid extra character which will appear on `blur event`.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try

Comment: This version works, but there are problems within the mask =(
Check this pull request for an update on this problem:

https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/pull/855